# Django get_object_or_404 is not defined

Tags: python, django, import

I am developing a standalone application which uses ORM of django. In my main application, I am using django's module of get_object_or_404.

I have imported it with all its dependencies when I run the script, it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/standAlone/tasks.py", line 48, in task1
NameError: global name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined
```

Here is my full script code:

```
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(
    DATABASE_ENGINE    = "django.db.backends.mysql",
    DATABASE_NAME      = "database name",
    DATABASE_USER      = "username",
    DATABASE_PASSWORD  = "password",
    DATABASE_HOST      = "host",
    DATABASE_PORT      = "3306",
    INSTALLED_APPS     = ("myApp",)
)
django.setup()
from django.db import models
from myApp.models import *
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404
from celery.decorators import task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger



app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://broker_url')

@app.task(name="task1")
def task1(recipe_pk):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=recipe_pk) #error occurs here
    recipe.status = 'Completed'
    recipe.save()
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: That's not your actual code; the error is happening on line 48 but there are less than that in the code you have posted.

Comment: there were many 'tasks' in my code having same function for testing purposes. Since I didn't want to make question too long and messy, I deleted the extra bits

Comment: Somewhere in _deleting the extra bits_, you also deleted the actual error.  The code you posted cannot have the error you describe.

Comment: I didn't, I was very careful while posting the question, the error occurs at the line I mentioned

Comment: Is your real code in separate files?  Are you _absolutely sure_ that the file which contains `recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=recipe_pk)` also contains `from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404`, and that the import occurs _above_ the call?

Comment: yes I am 100% sure

Comment: Then all I can do is ask you to post the real file.  We can't solve your problem from the edited version.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps you have a stale `.pyc` or `.pyo` file left over, and that file is getting used instead of the `.py` file.

Comment: You'd only need to post the first 48 lines, which can't be so bad.

Comment: Are you sure you set up django properly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238812/is-it-possible-to-use-django-models-module-only-in-my-project/39239467#39239467

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this double import of "django.shortcuts".